# Responsive Layout - Determining Zoom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

In a responsive layout how does the phone determine how far it zooms in when it lands on the site?

Here is an example:

http://eldoradodrillingcompany.com

If you look at it in your browser it looks great, but when you actually land on it on your phone it's like the zoom is too far in.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a meta tag in the `<head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I don't think `maximum-scale=1` is something the user wants here. The rest is OK.